# ElementaryOS Freya - Dropbox Icon

Tags: linux, icons, dropbox, tray

I'm having some troubles with dropbox icon on tray with ElementaryOS Freya

Dropbox is synchronizing, the unique problem is the icon on tray that I can't show anyway.

Procedures done:

1 - Instaled dropbox by .deb downloaded from dropbox site using `dpkg -i`

2 - Instaled by .tar downloaded from dropbox site using this:

```
$ cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
$ ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

3 - Instaled by Elementary repository using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dropbox
```

4 - I've deleted the folders   `~/.dropbox` ,   `~/.dropbox.dist` and executed the daemon again with   `$ dropbox start -i`

5 - I've put the code     `export DROPBOX_USE_LIBAPPINDICATOR=1`  in files:      `~/.bashrc`,     `~/xsessionrc`  and     `/etc/profile`.

6 - I've instaled the packages:     `pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox` and     `libappindicator1`

Any idea for fix?

Answer (score 12):

A quick fix I go into detail on [my blog here](http://www.srw2d.com/getting-dropbox-notification-working-in-elementary-os-freya/), but simply here:

1. Kill dropbox, and restart it so it shows

   ```
   dropbox stop && env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start
   ```
2. Go to the settings in dropbox after it starts up and select to not start at startup.
3. Go to system settings -> Applications, from the tab up top select "Startup" and add a command from the + button at the bottom left and there will be an input where you can enter in a command below and press enter to save:

   ```
   env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start
   ```

Restart and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I followed a similar process to the one in [this blog comment](http://entornosgnulinux.com/2014/08/24/indicador-de-dropbox-en-elementary-os-solucionado/#comment-1380).

The following script started Dropbox showing the icon on the tray as expected.

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10 && dropbox stop && env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start
```

To make it permanent, simply editing `dropbox.desktop` like they mention in the blog didn't work for me. 
Run the script and go to Dropbox's preferences. Untick "Start Dropbox on system startup". This will get rid of the .desktop file.

Now we create our own in the same place, `~/.config/autostart`, we can name it `dropbox-fix.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox (fixed)
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=/usr/bin/dropbox-fix.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

You should change `Exec=/usr/bin/dropbox-fix.sh` to where you have saved the script and make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running Dropbox, then click on Options and there should be an option that says show "Icon in tray" or something along those lines. Please let me know if this helps you or if you need more assistance.

Comment: When I click on Dropbox icon in dash, nothing happens, I think dropbox don't have a interface, the icon only starts the daemon

Comment: I understand, that same problem has just started with my dropbox as well. I have looked around online and nobody has a real solution to fix it yet. That is another dropbox like service called copy.com. If you refer it to your friends you will get more space. Somebody I know who uses copy.com has well over 5TB of storage. I will keep looking for a solution and I will let you know.